# some true font does not work when installed system wide

Tags: fonts

I copied my fonts into `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/myfonts`. Then I did `#fc-cache -fv`. `fc-list` actually show all the fonts in that folder. However, I cannot see some fonts in the ubuntu `fonts` app. For example: `Helvetica CE Regular.ttf: Helvetica CE:style=Regular`. If I double click the font and install it to `.local/share/fonts/` it actually works. I can see it in the fonts app. Why this happens? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the permission of those ttf was wrong. It was 640 which prevent other users to read. We need to change it to 644.